# Set Theory and Zorn Lemma

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Prove that there is a set $B\subseteq P(\mathbb N)$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb N:\mathbb N- n\in B$, every finite intersection of elements in B is not empty and for all $C\subseteq\mathbb N$ such that $C\not\in B$ there are $n$ elements in $B$ such that: $B_1\cap B_2\cap\dots B_n\cap C=\emptyset$. I would like a hint for this problem. I think I need to use Zorn's lemma on a partial order set with the $\subset$ partial order but I can't find the set.

Comment: Are you familiar with ultrafilters?  Any non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ should do the job.

Comment: Is it the following you want to prove?
$$\exists B\subseteq \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\forall n\in \mathbb N\\ \left(\mathbb N\setminus \{n\}\in B \land \forall X,Y\in B(X\cap Y\neq \varnothing) \land\\ \land \exists C\in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\left(C\not \in B\implies \exists B_1, \ldots B_n\left(\bigcap \limits_{k=1}^n\left(B_k\right)\cap C=\varnothing)\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: thanks @universalset, I'm not familiar with ultrafilters but I'm pretty sure There is a solution without that does not use this concept.

Comment: @GitGud, almost, except that only finite intersection of elements in $B$ should not be empty and note every 2 elements in $B$

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb N-n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Zorn's lemma one wants to later exploit maximality. One can easily construct a set which satisfies all but the last one. For example all the co-finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.

So the maximality should be used to prove the last property.

In that case, the other properties should define the partial order $(A,\leq)$. We start by the naive approach, using $\subseteq$ as the ordering, and see if we can bound chains using their union. In case that fails, we will see what can we do about it.

Take $A$ to be all the subsets $B\subseteq\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ with the first two properties being true. And order them by inclusion. Suppose that $\cal C$ is a chain in $A$, and consider $\bigcup\cal C$. It is not hard to see that it indeed have the wanted properties.

By Zorn's lemma there is a maximal element $B$. Now the usual maximality arguments can be used to show that the last property holds for $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the class consisting of all sets $\mathcal{B}\subseteq P(\mathbb{N})$ satisfying:

- $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N}\setminus\left\{n\right\}\in \mathcal{B}$;
- every finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ is non-empty.

Apply Zorn's lemma to $\mathscr{C}$ (ordered by inclusion). Any maximal element of $\mathscr{C}$ should do the job.

Comment: Can you elaborate?